# Which graphic card driver is safer?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, hybrid-graphics

I have an Asus Laptop with hybrid graphic card. Several days ago I installed Nvidia driver and now for time to time I change my graphic card preference(by Nvidia-Prime) between Intel and Geforce. I want to see is there any other way to make this automatic to not spend so much time for selecting the graphic card?
I've tried Bumblebee, but I really have problem on working with it.

Answer (score 0):

The nvidia prime indicator makes switching more easy.

source: [prime-indicator-lets-you-quickly-switch](http://www.webupd8.org/2014/01/prime-indicator-lets-you-quickly-switch.html)

Open a terminal and type the following commands to install the package and add the ppa.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install prime-indicator
```

---

Update:

To fix the glx info not found error, type the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install mesa-utils
```

You may have to reboot for the changes to take effect.

Also, the "safest" driver can be found if you open ubuntu software-center, select edit, software sources, and then click on the additional drivers tab. The safest driver is listed as "tested".

Comment: After installing, it shows "sh: 1: glxinfo: not found". And when I change it by usual prime option the screen goes to be dark. And It makes me to restart lightdm.

Comment: @sina I have updated the answer for this error.